# OneSignale works without IOS Push Up Certificate?

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, certificate, testflight, onesignal

I want to public my App. Some people test my App with TestFlight. The Push Up Noticication works very good. Now i read the "Ionic & Capacitor SDK Setup" again and there is one ponit that makes me confused. https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/generate-an-ios-push-certificate
The Push Up Certificate is required but it works without.
My guess: It works, because the App is downloaded from TestFlight (?). If i download the App from the App Store, the push up Noticication without the Certificate doesnt work? Or i need the Certificate just for security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push certificate is required for IOS.
You can simply use this tool. https://onesignal.com/provisionator
Then continue with step 3.